# Rule of "е" after a vowel

Tags: произношение

The rule is "е" sounds like "ye" after a vowel, does the  е[ye] have to be right in front of the vowel to sound like [ye] or can it be anywhere behind "e" throughout the word?

Comment: You mean, "right *behind* the vowel"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. If `e` is preceded by a vowel, it is read as `je`:

> мо**е**т, стира**е**т, убира**е**т, etc.

We will also read `e` as `je` if a words starts with the letter:

> **е**нот, **е**щё, **е**сли, etc.

If `e` is preceded by `ъ` or `ь`, we shall read it as `je` as well:

> подъ**е**зд, съ**е**зд, въ**е**зд, варень**е**, etc.

However, in words like `моeт` `e` is often reduced to `и` (`моит`), and words like `ещё` (see the second rule above) may be read as `йищё` (`если` will always be `jesl'i` since `e` is stressed). The reason is it's just simpler to pronounce the words like that. Technically, if you read `e` as `je` in those words, you'll be right, and no one will ever correct you. Many people will not even catch the difference. Anyway, it's important to note the reduction.

Comment: unfortunately this isn't accurate, a **stressed** **`e`** preceded by a vowel is read as **`je`**, the unstressed one is read as **`i`** - **`моИт`**, **`убираИт`**, **`стираИт`**, reduction into **`i`** occurs at the beginning as well unless there's a cluster of 2 consonants - **`йИнот`**, **`йИщё`**, but indeed **`йЭсли`**

Comment: i should correct myself, in **`если`** **Е** is not reduced due to being stressed, not because of the following consonants, initial **`е-`** is always pronounced as **`йи-`** unless stressed

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Better put it this way:

1. If `е` immediately follows a consonant, no [j] is added: `привет, тебе, же`.
2. Otherwise it gets a [j] sound in front of it: `ел, поел, съел, колье`.

Some words have both type 1 and type 2 `е`: `еле, веер, белеет, змееед`.

Same rule applies to `я, ё, ю`.

Minimal pairs to practise the distinction: `сел/съел` (sat/ate), `полёт/польёт` (flight/will pour), `полю/полью` (I weed/I will water), `чего/чьего` (what/whose), перо/Пьеро (feather/Pierrot).

Comment: I dont understand your statement you say “ if e immediately follows a consonant no [j] is added, but in привет the e here is follow by a consonant and sounds like ye

Comment: @Almonds812, I don't know what it sounds like when *you* say it but I do know a foreigner when they greet me with **привйет!** There is no **й** / y / [j] in **привет** which is what point 1 above says. To a Russian, **привет** and **привйет** sound *distinctly different*, while **конвеер** and **конвейер** sound *exactly the same*.

Comment: I have been to wikipedia, masterrussian.com, many youtube videos today, i have no i idea where you got that rule for no [j] immediately follows a consonant, in the word привет on wikipedia there is 100% clearly a [j], i also checked many russian blogs on russianpod101.com where they start the blog by saying привет, there is definitely a [j]

Comment: I am not just listening to it on wikipedia i am looking at its МФА also

Comment: I found the rule you are talking about but it turns out [j] is slightly lessoned but there is definitely still a [j] there

Comment: Can you share the rule you've found?

Comment: The IPA uses a superscript [j] to denote palatalization of a consonant. It is not the same as a standalone [j] sound. In [prʲɪˈvʲet] both [r] and [v] are soft. But you are are not saying [j] after [r], do you? I hope you don't.

Comment: Ok i know your right but i dont understand you, i hope you hep me i started learning 2 months ago and im confused,

Comment: When i listen to the wikipedia sound they use a hard [je] prevyet? Why is this

Comment: I am not saying j after r

Comment: Do you have skype can we text chat there , i have never struggled with anything like this before my skypername: almonds812