# Pronunciation of “нервный”

Tags: произношение

It is not proceeded by a vowel, why is it nyervный, i checked on ru wikipedia its nyervный
I really still dont understand the rules of e[je] im so confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pronounced without `j`, because:

- there is no vowel or `ъ`/`ь` before `е`,
- it does not start a word.

The consonant before becomes soft, `н'`.

Please also refer to the [other](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/17519/1274) answer.